# Somebody is reverse engineering my app. Should I afraid of stealing? Is it legal?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I have an Android app in Google Play store.

I've discovered **trough various Fabric events that somebody is reverse engeenering my app.**

I have a piracy checker which triggers if somebody installs the app not from the Google Play store, and he also made numerous IAPs without the payment being paid.

I know both of these things by Fabric custom events.

I also get false new user alarms from a Xiaomi phone, which is far a typical sympthom when somebody is launching the application many times - like when changing and trying the code again and again.

As far as I know:

**Reverse engineering for your own fun is absolutely legal.**

**But what if the guy decides he re-publish my app with some numbers and paramteres changed with some reskin?**

Also he have bought about 100 IAPS that would cost like 270$, but it was free for him because he changed the code.

Is it legal? Could I report it to Google or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well if you know this then can't you make your app more secure if that's possible ?

Comment: @VrushiPatel I already did the necessery steps, but the question is not this, also, you cannot ever protect your android app 100% against professional reverse engs, even the developer of proguard says that.

Comment: You can use Pro-guard rules in your project to avoid reverse engineering your app.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi OK

Comment: `Reverse engineering for your own fun is absolutely legal.` it is not if it is specified by license agreement. `But what if the guy decides he re-publish my app` We are developers, not lawyers. Is it legal, or not - is totally a lawyer question, not development. Such questions have no place at StackOverflow. As for IAPs - it is up to you to protect them. To be sure, you have to confirm them using server. Means you can add bought goods only when the IAP was reported to your server by google server

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko but pro-guard also solves the problem to avoid reverse engineer problem right?

Comment: no, it does not. It only makes it harder

Comment: Can you please explain me the reason why it makes harder @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: it obfuscates code. For details - just read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely kick off the process. If this is uploaded to the Play Store, it's an unlawful event as they will be stealing your IAP's.

If you can prove that they are using your code, it's a copyright violation and you should visit the guide at https://support.google.com/legal/answer/3110420 and follow the steps to report this right away.

Comment: Even if I failed to show and force users to "accept" my terms and conditions? (My bad)

Comment: You automatically have copyright over any work you do and if someone is stealing it, it's a violation of the Play Store rules. Google can't do anything about it if you don't report it. The terms and conditions you should show your users have nothing to do with the Google terms and conditions, so don't worry about that.